# Creat table smarty 2

Tags: php, smarty

I want to create a table smarty 2.

My goal is to display the categories and not just the subcategories.

I tried doing:

```
 <{foreach from=$super item=category_parent}>
 <{$category_parent.title}>
 <{/foreach}>
```

but it appears to me but I do want the categories!

Comment: Look console : http://www.jddemo.byethost24.com/smarty.png

Answer (score 1):

You describe what you tried, but you did not describe what results you actually got, or what output you wanted to see ('display the categories' is very vague, and I don't think you actually saw the subcategory titles instead).

I'm going to assume you want the title to display (perhaps one per row), but NOTHING was actually displayed.

$super might be empty - your screenshot did not make it clear that the top-level array was stored in the $super variable.

Sometimes debugging by printing the contents of the variable in question is handy:

```
<pre>{$super|@print_r}</pre>
```

That way you can confirm the variable name in that specific spot/scope.

Your template looks really odd:

```
<{ xxxx }>
```

won't result in valid html (if you're trying to generate html).  If you were trying to generate html and were viewing the result in a browser, the page may have been blank because of malformed html, but the data might have been in the raw html.  Take a look at the raw html generated (view source).

Perhaps try something like this:

```
{foreach from=$super item=category_parent}
<div>{$category_parent.title}</div>
{/foreach}
```